# Windows & Z-Position

Tags: windows, msdn

The [SetWindowPos function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx) allows re-ordering window layout on the Z-axis.

It works well for most windows, but I did notice certain windows are not
responding to it and returns zero (error).

Windows such as Task Manager, Resource Monitor, Computer Management, etc.
The pattern is that they belong among administrative tools. Might be so
by design.

Anyone has an idea why is it so? I just started working with MSDN interface,
so I might be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely running into this problem (from the SetWindowPos function notes):

> As part of the Vista re-architecture, all services were moved off the
>   interactive desktop into Session 0. hwnd and window manager operations
>   are only effective inside a session and cross-session attempts to
>   manipulate the hwnd will fail.